# Integrating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}dx$ for $0<a<1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm supposed to find the value of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}dx$ for $0<a<1$. I wanted to integrate over the upper semicircle of radius $R$, and take the limit as $R\to\infty$.

I'm fairly certain that the integral of the upper half of the circle $|z|=R$ will tend to $0$ as $R\to \infty$, so I should be left with

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x}dx=2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}_{z=i\pi}\left(\frac{e^{az}}{1+e^z}\right)=2\pi i\frac{e^{az}}{e^z}\biggr\vert_{z=i\pi}=2\pi ie^{(a-1)i\pi}$$

However, when I check my answer on Wolfram Alpha for say $a=1/2$, it says the value is $\pi$, which is clearly not what I would get. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't the residue theorem come with a factor of $2\pi i$ in front?  i.e., perhaps your answer should be something like $2 \pi i e^{(a-1)i\pi}$.  I think this gives you an answer of $2\pi$ for $a = 1/2$, so we're still off by a factor of 2 somewhere else...

Comment: Oh actually, when you expand your upper half circle to infinity, you encompass an infinite number of singularities, $z = i (2n+1) \pi$, for each non-negative integer $n$.  I believe you have to consider the residues at each one...

Comment: @nukeguy Yes I hadn't considered that!

Comment: I don't think you have to deal with the infinitely many poles here - how about taking a long thin rectangle  (height $2\pi i$, length $2R$), so that it encloses just the pole $\pi i$?

Comment: Your answer can't be right because it has an imaginary part, but the integrand is real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach 1.
  Suggested by Lost in a Maze.

Integrate $\frac{e^{az}}{1+e^z}$ along the rectangle with vertices $\pm R,$ $\pm R +2\pi i$ and let $R$ tend to $\infty$, we would have \begin{align}
\left(1-e^{2a\pi i}\right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} dx&=2\pi i\,\operatorname{Res} \left(\frac{e^{az}}{1+e^z}; \pi i\right)\\
&=-2\pi ie^{a\pi i}.\end{align}
This yields $$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} dx=\frac{\pi}{\sin a\pi}.$$

Approach 2.
If we make a substitution $t=e^x$, the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} dx$ will be $$
\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{a-1}}{1+t} dt.$$
This integral can be seen in so many books, for instance, see Gamelin's Complex Analysis, p.207. It can be evaluated by integration of $\frac{z^{a-1}}{1+z}$ around a keyhole contour.

Comment: This is great! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an utterly horrific approach. I will ignore issues of convergence/interchanging limits/playing fast and loose with differential operators.

**Step 1:** We note that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} \, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} \,dx + \int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} \, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} \, dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{(1-a)x}}{1+e^x} \, dx $$ by a substitution $x \mapsto -x$ and accordingly define the function $$F(a) := \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} \, dx$$ By the above, we would like to compute $I(a) := F(a) + F(1-a)$. In fact, for this argument it will be necessary to work with $$G(b) := \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-bx}}{1+e^{-x}} \, dx$$ which is evidently not so different, since $F(a) = G(1-a)$ and $G(a) + G(1-a) = I(a)$.

**Step 2:** Let $D$ denote the differentiation operator $f \mapsto D[f]:= f'$. Differentiating under the integral sign, we note that $$D^k[G](b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^{k} e^{-bx}}{1+e^{-x}} \, dx$$ Accordingly, we compute as follows; note here that we are swapping a sum and integral: $$(1+e^{D})[G](b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(2-x+\frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots \right) e^{-bx}}{1+e^{-x}} \, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-bx} \, dx = \frac{1}{b}$$ having used the power series development of $1+e^{-x}$.

**Step 3:** We should now compute $$G(b) = \frac{1}{1+e^{D}} \left[ \frac{1}{b} \right]$$ We expand $(1+e^{D})^{-1}$ as follows: $$\frac{1}{1+e^{D}} = \sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^{k} e^{kD} = \sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^{k} \sum_{\ell \ge 0} \frac{(kD)^{\ell}}{\ell!} = \sum_{k\ge 0} \sum_{\ell \ge 0} (-1)^{k} \frac{k^{\ell}}{\ell!} D^{\ell}$$ Now, noting that $D^{\ell} [1/b] = (-1)^{\ell} \ell! b^{-(\ell + 1)}$, we have $$\frac{1}{1+e^{D}} \left[ \frac{1}{b} \right] = \sum_{k\ge 0} \sum_{\ell \ge 0} (-1)^{k} \frac{k^{\ell}}{\ell!} (-1)^{\ell} \ell! b^{-(\ell + 1)} = \sum_{k\ge 0} \sum_{\ell \ge 0} (-1)^{k+\ell} k^{\ell} b^{-(\ell+1)}$$ $$ = \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{b} \sum_{\ell \ge 0} \left(\frac{-k}{b} \right)^{\ell} = \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{b} \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{b}} = \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{b+k}$$ Assuming all manipulations are valid, we have shown the  identity $$\boxed{G(b) = \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{b+k}}$$

**Step 4:** Finally, we must compute $I(a) = G(a) + G(1-a)$. We have $$I(a) = \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+a} + \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1-a} = \frac{1}{a} + \sum_{k\ge 1} (-1)^k \frac{2a}{a^2 - k^2}$$ Indeed, this is a well-known series representation of the function $\pi \csc(\pi a)$, which can be shown by the "Herglotz trick." $\blacksquare$